# url parameters regex

Tags: php, regex

I've created my own newsletter module and come across one (big) problem.
The system formats all urls with additional parameters to keep track of the clicks in google analytics.

e.g.
A url like this

> http://www.domain.com

becomes like this

> http://www.domain.com/&utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=e-mail&utm_campaign=test

and a url like this

> http://www.domain.com/?page=1

becomes like this

> http://www.domain.com/?page=1&utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=e-mail&utm_campaign=test

The first example is bogus. I know the first ampersand has to be replaced by an ampersand and that's where the problem occurs. 
I'm using this pattern to extract url's

```
$pattern = array('#[a-zA-Z]+://([-]*[.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_/-?&%\{\}])*#');
$replace = array('\\0&utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=e-mail&utm_campaign=test');
$body = preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$body);
```

Can anybody help me with a correct and working regex, so the first url parameter always contains a questionmark in stead of an ampersand?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `strpos` + concatenation?

Comment: if an answer solves your problem, you should accept it as a good answer by marking the green V under it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use

```
if(strpos($string,'?') !== false)
//add with ampersand
else
//add with question mark
```

Answer (score 0):

Not regex, but it would work. All it does is check for a ? and if it isn't found, change the first & to a question mark.:

```
$url = (substr_count($url, '?')>0) ? $url : str_replace('&', '?', $url, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach would be to look for a string like `http://...&` where the `...` contains no `?` question mark or other delimiters:

```
= preg_replace('#(http://[^\s"\'<>?&]+)&#', '$1?', $src);
```

But it's probably best if you use a restricted instead of a negated character class:

```
$src = preg_replace('#(http://[\w/.]+)&#', '$1?', $src);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution fixes all urls which have a query beginning with a `&` (and are missing the `?`):

```php
$re = '%([a-zA-Z]+://[^?&\s]+)&(utm_source=newsletter)%';
$body = preg_replace($re, '$1?$2', $body);
```